# WP Advanced Custom Fields data after import

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I imported Custom Fields into my WordPress site from my staging server. Certain pages are no longer working.

I've tracked this down to a data issue. I went into the database and removed all entries from the wp_postmeta table that I am referencing on my page that is failing. I then went back into a post that was not working and did an update. That post now works.

This isn't a realistic approach since there are hundreds of posts that I would have to manually update. Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Can you do it programmatically? Or even just running a few SQL statements?

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I actually ended up finding that the reason there are multiple records are due to multiple revisions.

Comment: No worries, glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that each revision is stored in the database.

The original developer of the site i'm working on was displaying fields incorrectly.

If a field was called list_items, they were saying post.list_items instead of post.get_field('list_items'). Since there were multiple revisions in the database the DOM was displaying an array.